# WordNetlemmatizer error - all alphabets are lemmatized

Tags: python, pandas, nltk, wordnet, lemmatization

I am trying to lemmatize my dataset for sentiment analysis - What should I do to get the expected output rather than the current output? Input file is a csv - stored as DataFrame object.

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('xyz.csv')
```

Here is my code

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
list1_ = []
for file_ in dataset:
    result1 = dataset['Content'].apply(lambda x: [lemmatizer.lemmatize(y) for y in x])
    list1_.append(result1)
dataset = pd.concat(list1_, ignore_index=True)
```

Expected

```
>> lemmatizer.lemmatize('cats')
>> [cat]
```

Current output

```
>> lemmatizer.lemmatize('cats')
>> [c,a,t,s]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**

```
result1 = dataset['Content'].apply(lambda x: [lemmatizer.lemmatize(y) for y in x.split()])
```

Lemmatizer takes in any string as an input.

If `dataset['Content']` columns are strings, iterating through a string would be iterating through the characters not "words", e.g.

```
>>> from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
>>> wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
>>> x = 'this is a foo bar sentence, that is of type str'
>>> [wnl.lemmatize(ch) for ch in x]
['t', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'f', 'o', 'o', ' ', 'b', 'a', 'r', ' ', 's', 'e', 'n', 't', 'e', 'n', 'c', 'e', ',', ' ', 't', 'h', 'a', 't', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'o', 'f', ' ', 't', 'y', 'p', 'e', ' ', 's', 't', 'r']
```

So you would have to first word tokenize your sentence string, e.g.:

```
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize
>>> [wnl.lemmatize(word) for word in x.split()]
['this', 'is', 'a', 'foo', 'bar', 'sentence,', 'that', 'is', 'of', 'type', 'str']
>>> [wnl.lemmatize(ch) for ch in word_tokenize(x)]
['this', 'is', 'a', 'foo', 'bar', 'sentence', ',', 'that', 'is', 'of', 'type', 'str']
```

another e.g.

```
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize
>>> x = 'the geese ran through the parks'
>>> [wnl.lemmatize(word) for word in x.split()]
['the', u'goose', 'ran', 'through', 'the', u'park']
>>> [wnl.lemmatize(ch) for ch in word_tokenize(x)]
['the', u'goose', 'ran', 'through', 'the', u'park']
```

But to get a more accurate lemmatization, you should get the sentence word tokenized and pos-tagged, see https://github.com/alvations/earthy/blob/master/FAQ.md#how-to-use-default-nltk-functions-in-earthy